# How to find all binary numbers in base $10$ s.t. that its divisible by its own numerical value in base $2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Consider $N=1010$. Its numerical value in base-$2$ is $2^3+2=10$ and $10 \mid 1010$. How to find all positive integers like $N$?

Its easy to see that $n$ is in the form $10^{n_1}+10^{n_2}+...+10^{n_k}$, where $n_1>n_2>...>n_k \ge 0$. We need
$$ 2^{n_1}+2^{n_2}+...+2^{n_k} \mid 10^{n_1}+10^{n_2}+...+10^{n_k} $$

I'll be very grateful if you could share your thoughts on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for numbers $k$ such that $k$ divides $bd(k)$, where $bd()$ reinterprets the binary representation of $k$ as a decimal number.

It's clear that if $k$ is a qualifying number, then $2k$ is also, since $bd(2k) = 10\cdot bd(k)$. It's also easy to find that $10^m$ qualifies, for any $m$. This gives us a set that qualifies: every number of the form $2^a\cdot 10^b$: $\{1,2,4,8,10,16,20,\ldots\}$

In the range to $500$ that I investigated, two more "primitive" numbers qualified: $21$ and $273$. Of course numbers $2^a\cdot 21$ and $2^a\cdot 273$ would also be valid. The binary form of these, $10101$ and $100010001$, suggests an avenue for further investigation.